# EEPROM Arduino library for ESP8266 is not working

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, eeprom

I am trying to use **EEPROM** library from **Arduino** framework for my **ESP8266** project (NodeMCU). I am using *Atom* with *Platformio*.

Initialization of EEPROM is attempted at *void setup()* in *main.cpp*:

```
EEPROM.begin(80);
```

The compiler throws an error at this line with:

```
request for member 'begin' in '0', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

This is strange as I just follow a [simple example from GitHub](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/examples/eeprom_write/eeprom_write.ino).

I include *<EEPROM.h>* just as *<Arduino.h>* and many others (<ESP8266WiFi.h>, <ESP8266WebServer.h>, <ESP8266mDNS.h>). Platformio has created *.pio\build\nodemcuv2\lib32c\EEPROM* directory with *EEPROM.cpp.o* inside but compilation fails.

How can I make it work and what else should I check to find the problem?

Comment: run the example code that is in the Arduino IDE

Comment: Instead of describing your code, *show* your code.

Comment: @Majenko, it's almost 2.5K lines. Not easy to bring the relevant part quickly.

Comment: Then write some code that is only a few lines and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Exactly what @Majenko said - if this is a problem then it should be easy to demonstrate in 10 lines of code. If you can't reproduce it in 10 lines of code then you have a very large clue as to what's going on.

Comment: you have not the right EEPROM library.

Comment: Have you tried compiling one the examples supplied with the ESP8266 Arduino BSP (after adding `#include <Arduino.h>` to the top, of course) - maybe the `eeprom_write` one? If that works, you will be able to narrow it to something else in your code. Otherwise, you've probably got a corrupt install, or wrong `platformio.ini` configuration. You didn't add EEPROM to the `lib_deps`, did you? As you should be using the espressif8266 platform provided EEPROM library.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. At first I thought it's about the library I use (just as @Juraj supposed). Then your advices to try pure examples (which proved to work fine) led me to search for conflicts.
Eventually I found an external lib that had *#define EEPROM* (nothing to do with Arduino, it's for other MCUs to communicate).
I was misguided by a vague compiler error. Normally for a direct naming conflict (as in this case) it says clearly: *"redefinition of ..."*
So be warned, this type of error should be considered as a conflict to look for.
Once again, many thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: The problem here is that these symbols exist in different layers. The problem one was a "preprocessor macro" which gets replaced verbatim in a first pass through the code. Only once that is done is the code compiled - so first off all references to EEPROM get replaced with `0` (I guess) and *then* it's compiled, which leaves you with `0.begin(80);` that of course fails to compile. There's no redefinition to report an error on.